# Comma inside a column value

Tags: apache-spark

I am using spark 3 and below is my code to read a CSV file

```
package spark.ny.project;

import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        SparkSession session = SparkSession.builder().appName("Sample App").master("local[*]").getOrCreate();
        
        session.sparkContext().setLogLevel("ERROR");
        
        Dataset<Row> df = session.read().format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("quote","*" ).option("sep", ",")
                .load("/home/deepak/sample_dataset/*.csv");
        df.printSchema();
        df.show(false);
        
        

    }

}
```

and below is the content of csv file

```
CallType , Methods
Internal , *ApplyChanges,ApproveCase*
```

and below is the output that I am getting

```
root
 |-- CallType : string (nullable = true)
 |--  Methods: string (nullable = true)

+---------+---------------+
|CallType | Methods       |
+---------+---------------+
|Internal | *ApplyChanges |
+---------+---------------+
```

The second value in the methods column is missing. If I refer to the documentation https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv#features, when the quote option is used the delimiter inside the quotes, would be ignored.

I am not able to figure out why I am getting that output and how can I tell spark not to treat a comma inside a column value as a delimiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that's because of the white space. The quote must immediately follow the separator (comma). You can get around this by specifying `ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace` and `ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace`.

```
Dataset<Row> df = session.read().format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
                         .option("quote", "*")
                         .option("sep", ",")
                         .option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", "true")
                         .option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace", "true")
                         .load("/home/deepak/sample_dataset/*.csv");
```